# How to combine AWS API Gateway and Step functions to provide Restful API Service

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I deployed a GET method in AWS API Gateway which is then integrated with AWS Step Functions as backend.

The Problem is the integration with Step Functions only allowed through Http "Post" method.

That means I set input to Step Functions but can not get the output of the Step Functions.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you provide your use cases why you want this? It doesn't seem like a reasonable approach.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do it the same way I did, by using a Lambda function to invoke the step function and return it's result from within the Lambda function, if it runs in less than 30 seconds.

It would look like this API Gateway <--> Lambda <--> Step function

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41773504/7243001

Comment: API Gateway will timeout request at ~30s. I don't think the step function execution will be done by then.