# AWS API Gateway with Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-step-functions

I want a sample to integrate AWS API Gateway with Step Function. I have read this tutorial [Creating a Step Functions API Using API Gateway](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/tutorial-api-gateway.html) but that tutorial needs me to send request in format of

```
{    
"input": "{}",    
"name": "PostmanExecution",    
"stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:us-east-1:123456789012:stateMachine:Custom" 
}
```

I want to send normal request and configure this **stateMachineArn** in API Gateway only, so that clients dont need to send this.

Answer (score 20):

Create your API Gateway resource and method. Then in the "Method Execution" settings, in the Integration Request, use these settings:

- Integration type: AWS Service
- AWS Region: *your region*
- AWS Service: Step Functions
- AWS Subdomain: *your subdomain if you have one - I left it blank*
- HTTP method: POST
- Action: StartExecution
- Execution role: *needs to be a role with StepFunction start execute policy, such as arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSStepFunctionsFullAccess*
- Credentials cache: *I left this as default*
- Content Handling: Passthrough

Then the magic. Futher down, under Body Mapping Templates:

- Request body passthrough: Never
- Add mapping template : application/json

Futher down in the template text box:

```
#set($input = $input.json('$'))
{
   "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input)",
   "stateMachineArn": "arn:aws:states:eu-west-1:123456789012:stateMachine:yourStepFunctionName"
}
```

This will pass the json payload posted to API Gateway through to the Step Function.

Omit the execution name so that each call to API Gateway creates a new execution.

Comment: Any Idea how to add your resourceTemplate to a CloudFormation template?

Comment: @Console i just posted a viable solution using CloudFormation

Comment: I wanted to form the stateMachineArn with region and account id populating dynamically. I was able to get the account id from `$context.accountId` but not able to find anything that gives the current region name. In my template `stateMachineArn` looks like this now, `"arn:aws:states:us-east-1:$context.accountId:stateMachine:AbcStateMachine"` Any idea how I can get the current region dynamically.

Comment: Any idea on how you would add additional params to the input? For instance, the cognito user email: ($context.authorizer.claims.email)  It would have to be in the "input" as that's what gets passed to the lambda. Not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to expose 2 endpoints by using API Gateway, one to start the execution and the second to check the execution status.

There is no need to use a lambda for this actions nor indicate the step function arn by parameters.

The solution CloudFormation template is:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  The turtle calculator, a dummy slow calculator for comprehensive code example
Parameters:
  OpenAPIS3File:
    Description: '"openapi.yaml" file location'
    Default: ./openapi.yaml
    Type: String

Resources:
  Workflow:
    Type: AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine
    Properties:
      StateMachineName: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-state-machine
      RoleArn: !GetAtt StateExecutionRole.Arn
      DefinitionString: !Sub |
        {
          ...
        }

  Api:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: random-workflow
      Name: !Sub ${AWS::StackName}-api
      DefinitionBody:
        'Fn::Transform':
          Name: AWS::Include
          Parameters:
            Location: !Ref OpenAPIS3File
```

And the OpenAPI configuration is:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.1
info:
  title: Api Mocker
  description: Automated testing application for TGR
  contact:
    name: Patagonia-IT
    url: http://www.patagonia-it.com
    email: contacto@patagonia-it.com
  license:
    name: Apache 2.0
    url: https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html
  version: 1.0.0

x-amazon-apigateway-request-validators:
  params:
    validateRequestParameters: true
    validateRequestBody: false

x-amazon-apigateway-request-validator: params

paths:
  /workflow:
    post:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        credentials:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ ApiGatewayStepFunctionsRole, Arn ]
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/StartExecution
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseTemplates:
              application/json: |
                '{ "executionId": "$input.json('executionArn').split(':').get(7) }'
        requestTemplates:
          application/json:
            Fn::Sub: |-
              {
                "input": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.json('$'))",
                "name": "$context.requestId",
                "stateMachineArn": "${Workflow}"
              }
      summary: Start workflow instance
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/200Execution'
        403:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/Error'
  /workflow/{executionId}:
    get:
      x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
        credentials:
          Fn::GetAtt: [ ApiGatewayStepFunctionsRole, Arn ]
        uri:
          Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:states:action/DescribeExecution
        httpMethod: POST
        type: aws
        responses:
          default:
            statusCode: 200
            responseTemplates:
              application/json: |-
                #set ($status = $input.json('status'))
                {
                #if($status == '"SUCCEEDED"')
                  "output": $util.parseJson($input.json('output')),
                #end
                  "status": $status
                }
        requestTemplates:
          application/json:
            Fn::Sub: |-
              {
                "executionArn": "arn:aws:states:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:execution:${Workflow.Name}:$input.params().path.get('executionId')"
              }
      summary: Workflow execution status
      responses:
        200:
          $ref: '#/components/responses/200ExecutionDetails'
```

I have commited a working example in github in https://github.com/jvillane/aws-sam-step-functions-lambda